# how can I stop animation buildup in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

I have the following script to open a side menu.
The menu opens line by line.
But if you rapidly click the menu button there is a animation buildup.
How can I stop this from happening? Tried with .stop(true) and .finish() before .animate but did not get the desired effect. I'm new to jQuery so I'm probably doing something wrong.

```
        var s = 0;
        var navMenu = document.getElementById("nav_menu");
        var navBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
        var speed = 100;

            function menuOpen() {
                if (s==0){

                    $("#nav_menu").scrollTop(0);
                    navBtn.classList.add('close');
                    navMenu.style.zIndex = "4";
                    navMenu.style.overflowY = 'auto';

                    $('ul').each(function() {
                        $(this).children().each(function(i) {
                            $(this).delay(i * speed).animate({
                                left: 0
                            });
                        });
                    });

                    s++;

                    $("li").promise().done(function() {
                        navMenu.style.zIndex = "4";
                        navMenu.style.overflowY = 'auto';
                    });

                } else {

                    navBtn.classList.remove('close');


                    $('ul').each(function() {
                        $(this).children().each(function(i) {
                            $(this).delay(i * speed).animate({
                                left: "100%"
                            });

                        });
                    });

                    s=0;

                    $("li").promise().done(function() {
                        navMenu.style.zIndex = "0";
                        navMenu.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
                    });


                };

            };
```

Please explain your answer if possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, animation must be stops with `stop()` method of jQuery, please check with your code. you have to call `stop()` first and then have to call `animate()`

```
$(this).stop().animate({left: 0},i * speed);

$(this).stop().animate({left: "100%"},i * speed);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast reply. But this does not work.
It messes with the animation loop. It does stop the animations. But just the ones that where running up to the time I clicked the button. They fold but the rest of the lines just open together.

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle and provide link?

Comment: Jsfiddle does not show the animations so I uploaded the files here:
http://mgolan.com/temp/menu/

I've was able to create the effect I'm trying to achieve with CSS animations with a demo here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485115/how-can-i-identify-when-the-opening-closing-css-animation-ends-with-javascript

but this has other problems

Comment: check my modification on answer, now stop working without delay. it may be help to you.

Comment: not working. The first few lines runs much faster then the rest and the animation gets totally mixed up if you click the open/close button a few times.
But what you wrote made me think that maybe the problem is with the index loop. Is there a way to track that? If'll know which index row just started animating I might be able to reverse it once the button is clicked again.